# Use multiline regex on cat output

Tags: sql, regex, bash, awk, grep

I've the following file `queries.sql` that contains a number of queries, structured like this:

```
/* Query 1 */
SELECT cab_type_id,
       Count(*)
FROM   trips
GROUP  BY 1;

/* Query 2 */
SELECT passenger_count,
       Avg(total_amount)
FROM   trips
GROUP  BY 1;

/* Query 3 */
SELECT passenger_count,
       Extract(year FROM pickup_datetime),
       Count(*)
FROM   trips
GROUP  BY 1,
          2;
```

Then I've written a regex, that finds all those queries in the file:

```
/\*[^\*]*\*/[^;]*;
```

What I'd like to achieve is the following:

1. Select all the queries with the regex.
2. Prefix each query with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`
3. Execute each query and output the results to a new file. That means, query 1 will create a file `q1.txt` with the corresponding output, query 2 create `q2.txt` etc.

One of my main challenges (there are no problems, right? ;-)) is, that I'm rather unfamiliar with the linux bash I've to use.

I tried `cat queries.sql | grep '/\*[^\*]*\*/[^;]*;'` but that doesn't return anything.

So a solution could look like:

```
count = 0
for query in (cat queries.sql | grep 'somehow-here-comes-my-regex') do
    count = $count+1
    query = 'EXPLAIN ANALYZE '+query
    psql -U postgres -h localhost -d nyc-taxi-data -c query > 'q'$count'.txt'
```

Except from: that doesn't work and I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: just a tip: `grep 'somehow-here-comes-my-regex' queries.sql` do the same as `cat queries.sql | grep 'somehow-here-comes-my-regex'`

Comment: Nice to know, thanks!

Comment: @samwise, would your current `psql` command not require password string?

Comment: No, it's working like this. It's just in a docker for a benchmark if have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to omit spaces for variable assignments.

The following script would help. Save it in a file eg.: `explain.sh`, make it executable using `chmod 0700 explain.sh` and run in the following way: `./explain.sh query.sql`.

```
#!/bin/bash

qfile="$1"

# number of queries
n="$(grep -oP '(?<=Query )[0-9]+ ' $qfile)"

count=1
for q in $n; do
    # Corrected solution, modified after the remarks of @EdMorton
    qn="EXPLAIN ANALYZE $(awk -v n="Query $q" 'flag; $0 ~ n {flag=1} /;/{flag=0}' $qfile)"
    #qn="EXPLAIN ANALYZE $(awk -v n=$q "flag; /Query $q/{flag=1} /;/{flag=0}" $qfile)"
    # psql -U postgres -h localhost -d nyc-taxi-data -c "$qn" > q$count.txt
    echo "$qn" > q$count.txt
    count=$(( $count + 1 ))
done
```

First of all, the script accounts for one argument (your example input `query.sql` file). It reads out the number of queries and save into a variable `n`. Then in a `for` loop it iterates through the query numbers and uses awk to extract the number `n` query and append EXPLAIN ANALYZE to the beginning. Then you can run your `psql` with the desired query. Here I commented out the psql part. This example script only creates qN.txt files for each explain query.

**UPDATE:**

The `awk` part: It is possible to use a shell variable in awk using the `-v` flag. Here we creates an ***awk variable*** `n` with the value of the `q` ***shell variable***. `n` is used to create the starter pattern ie: Query 1. `awk -v n="Query $q" 'flag; $0 ~ n {flag=1} /;/{flag=0}' $qfile` matches everything between `Query 1` and the first occurence of a semi-colon (`;`) excluding the line of `Query 1` from `query.sql`. The `$(...)` means command-substitution in bash, thus we can save the output of a shell command into a variable. Here we save the output of awk and prefix it with the EXPLAIN ANALYZE string.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns) is a great answer about awk pattern matching.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Would you mind to briefly explain the line ```qn="EXPLAIN ANALYZE $(awk -v n=$q "flag; /Query $q/{flag=1} /;/{flag=0}" $qfile)"```?

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton for the remark. I intended to use: `qn="EXPLAIN ANALYZE $(awk -v n=$q 'flag; $0 ~ n {flag=1} /;/{flag=0}' $qfile)"`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is what you're looking for:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\0' '{print "EXPLAIN ANALYZE", $0}' queries.sql |
while IFS= read -r -d '' query; do
    psql -U postgres -h localhost -d nyc-taxi-data -c "$query" > "q$((++count)).txt"
do
```

The awk statement outputs each query as a NUL-terminated string, the shell loop reads it as such one at a time and calls psql on it. Simple, robust, efficient, etc...